# Mysql join table group by user id and score result with set max date

Tags: mysql

I am developing a WordPress website for e learning. So one student attends the course, many times and scored the mark many times. Now I need to get one id with score and last record. I have tried many examples, but am able to get the result. I have given below my code.

```
SELECT m.id
     , m.email
     , t.id_tracking
     , t.user_id
     , FROM_UNIXTIME(t.date)
     , t.score
     , t.groupe_id
  FROM tracking t
  join membres m
 WHERE t.id_tracking IN (
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM tracking
GROUP BY user_id
)
```

I have used about the query I don't know what I did wrong

```
user_id     email               score     date
  1       test@testmail.com      78       15-06-2019      
  1       test@testmail.com      89       12-08-2019
  2       sam@testmail.com       66       24-03-2018
  2       sam@testmail.com       44       19-07-2019
  3       siv@testmail.com       98       09-02-2019
  3       siv@testmail.com       78       13-08-2020
```

I need to get result below like

```
user_id   email               score     date
   1     test@testmail.com    89       12-08-2019
   2     sam@testmail.com     44       19-07-2019
   3     siva@testmail.com    98       09-08-2020
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the relationship between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your DB but,
Have you tried like this...

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM process_table ORDER BY date desc) tbl1 
GROUP BY
  tbl1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` email/user_id and select maximum of `date` from each group, by converting the date to a UNIX TIMESTAMP, like this

```
    SELECT user_id, email, score, FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)))
    FROM tableName 
    GROUP BY user_id
```